# Why is my tmp folder created by cloudinary not deleted by cloudinary after completion of upload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cloudinary

So, I was trying to create a upload Post feature for my app where I will submit the file from frontend ,file goes to backend and gets uploaded to cloud servers of Cloudinary. But before that,a "tmp" folder is created in the backend where the file is stored ,so that it eases the process of upload into cloudinary servers .But once the file upload to cloudinary is complete ,the file does not get deleted from the "tmp" folder. Now I don't want to burden my backend with these unneccesary files . Is there a way to facilitate automatic delete? because if I manually try to delete the file right after upload ,React UI crashes with this error

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {code}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Here is my code

```
import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary'
function funct(num, req, res) {
    //configuration for cloud storage
    
    let file = req.files.photo;
    

    cloudinary.uploader.upload(file.tempFilePath, {folder:"Social_Media_posts"}, async (err, result) => {
        try {
            const { description, firstname, lastname, imageUrl, location, userId } = req.body
            //Both file and desc present
            if (num === 1) {
                //creating a new post record in database
                const newPost = new Post({
                    //from token verification
                    userId,
                    description,
                    postUrl: result.url,
                    firstname,
                    lastname,
                    imageUrl,
                    location,
                })
                
                //saving the record
                const ans = await newPost.save();
                //deleteFilesFromFolder(file.tempFilePath)
                res.status(201).send({ "status": "success", "message": ans, color: "green" })
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            res.send({ "status": "failed", "message": error, color: "red" })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "objects are not valid as a react child" error is thrown when you try to pass an object directly to a React component as a prop or child. To fix this error, you need to convert the array, for example, into a valid React child by iterating over its values and rendering them as React elements. This will allow React to render the object as part of the component's output, without throwing an error.

```
 import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
    const staff = [
        {name: 'Billy', role: 'admin'},
        {name: 'Sally', role: 'contributor'}
    ];

    const hq = {
        state: 'Nebraska',
        country: 'USA',
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {staff.map(user => (
                <div key={user.name}>
                    <p>{user.name}</p>
                    <p>{user.role}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
            
            <h1>HQ</h1>
            <p>State: {hq.state}</p>
            <p>Country: {hq.country}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```